# C# / EntityFramework - Accessing and entity is raising System.ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am fairly new `EntityFramework` so I hope I am going about this in the correct way.

I have a `DbContext` class:

```
public class UsersDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<DbUsersModel> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DbApplicationsModel> Applications { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DbImageModel> Images { get; set; }
}
```

This is for a `code-first` database that has the structure: Each `DbUsersModel` has multiple `DbApplicationsModel` elements, and each `DbApplicationsModel` has multiple `DbImageModel` elements.

Given an `DbImageModel.ImageTag`, I would like to obtain in the `DbApplicationsModel` that it belongs to.

I can easily grab the `DbImageModel` information based on the `DbImageModel.ImageTag` property using the code:

```
using (UsersDbContext ctx = new UsersDbContext())
{
    DbImageModel image = ctx.Images.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ImageTag == imageTag);
    if (image != null)
    {
        return image;
    }
}
```

This returns an instance of `DbImageModel` correctly, however, in the parent class (where `image` is returned to), I cannot access `image.Applications` because the `System.ObjectDisposedException` exception is fired, presumably because I'm trying to access `image.Applications` outside the `using`.

**Is there any way force the `context` to get `image.Applications` inside the `using` and retain it so that the information can be accessed outside the `using` code?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, instead of lazy-loading applications do eager loading (by [including](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220213%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) related entities into resultset):

```
using (UsersDbContext ctx = new UsersDbContext())
{
    DbImageModel image = ctx.Images.Include(i => i.Applications)
                            .FirstOrDefault(s => s.ImageTag == imageTag);
    if (image != null)        
        return image;        
}
```

With lazy-loading EF returns proxy classes which hold reference to `DbContext`. This reference is used when you are trying to get related entities later. If context is disposed at that time, you see *ObjectDisposedException*.

Eager loading loads related entities at same time when main entity is loaded.

Suggested reading: [Loading Related Entities with Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)

Comment: This looks promising, but I'm seeing a `cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type`. Any ideas how to investigate this?

Comment: @Brett by default there is available only Include method which accepts `string` with navigation property name. Include method with property selector expression (which I used) defined in `QueryableExtensions` class in *System.Data.Entity* namespace. Make sure you have added that namespace. Also I think it was added for EF 6. In previous version you can use `Include("Applications")`

Comment: I wasn't referencing `System.Data.Entity`. Good to go now! Very helpful...thanks!